# Codeigniter MySQL Balance after Performing Issues

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have following table & need to get the following output.

```
+---------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
| item_id | item_name | qty  |  status  | unit_price |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
|       1 | A         |  161 | purchase |       7.50 |
|       2 | A         |  108 | purchase |       8.50 |
|       3 | B         |  100 | purchase |      10.00 |
|       4 | A         |  -74 | issue    |       7.50 |
|       5 | A         | -100 | issue    |       8.50 |
|       6 | B         |  -24 | issue    |      10.00 |
+---------+-----------+------+----------+------------+
```

## Desired Output

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A         |  87 |       7.50 |
| A         |   8 |       8.50 |
| B         |  76 |      10.00 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

I used the following query.

```
select item_name, qty, unit_price from stock group by unit_price
```

## JavaScript

```
var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

                jData.data.forEach(data => {
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +                      
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].up+ '"></td>' +

                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                    })
                }
```

## Outs

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| A         |  87 |       7.50 |
| A         |  87 |       7.50 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

But didn't get the expected output. What can be modified in my query to do that. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `select item_name, SUM(qty), unit_price from stock group by unit_price, item_name`

Comment: @ Cid. When applied your modification in the query, only the (-) values outs. That's are, A - > -74, B -> -24

Comment: @MCITTrends: Cid provided the correct query for your use case... That's a simple aggregate query and it will return your expected result.

Comment: @ Cid. Thank you for your suggestion on my question. That returns the expected result in PhPMyadmin. Can you see my JavaScript edit.

Comment: I need to list the balances through datatables view and relevant JavaScript as mentioned. If I used the above script that outs two records of same item as edited. I think my array values are outed. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work if you only access the first index of your data array

The following should work

```
var jData = JSON.parse(data);
if (jData.status == true) 
{

    jData.data.forEach(objItem => {
        $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
            '<td ><span id="product" >' + objItem.item_name + '</span>' +
            '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + objItem.item_id + '">' +
            '</td>' +                       
            '<td class="text-center">' + objItem.qty + '</td>' +                      
            '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + objItem.up+ '"></td>' +

            '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
    });
}
```